# Function that always throws - A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-nothing

Why is the following code wrong?

```kotlin
fun alwaysThrow() {
    throw Error("Sorry")
}

fun checkNumber(arg: Int): Int {
    if (arg > 10) {
        return arg
    } 
    alwaysThrow()
}

fun main() {
    try {
        checkNumber(20)
    } catch (e: Error) {
        println("Error caught: ${e.message}")
    }
}
```

The function `checkNumber` fails to compile with the error:

> A 'return' expression required in a function with a block body ('{...}')

I don't understand why, since nothing will ever get executed past `alwaysThrow`.

Is there a way to tell the compiler?

For some reason this code *does* compile:

```kotlin
fun checkNumber(arg: Int): Int{
    if (arg > 10) {
        return arg
    } 
    throw Error("Sorry")
}

fun main() {
    try {
        checkNumber(1)
    } catch (e: Error) {
        println("Error caught: ${e.message}")
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler can't necessarily make assumptions about what functions will do. For example, what if, after `checkNumber()` was compiled, the `alwaysThrow()` function were changed so it _doesn't_ always throw an exception, and then recompiled? — (That would be different if the function were defined to return `Nothing`, as Vadik says, or if it had a [contract](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew13.html#contracts) indicating that it never returned normally — as it then changing it to return a value would clearly break binary compatibility.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can tell about that to Kotlin compiler. That's why you need [`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html) type:

```kotlin
fun alwaysThrow(): Nothing {
    throw Error("Sorry")
}
```

> [Nothing](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html) has no instances. You can use Nothing to represent "a value that never exists": for example, if a function has the return type of Nothing, it means that it never returns (always throws an exception).